# ASP.NET & jQuery multi-select dropdownlist, get selected values

Tags: asp.net, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have an .aspx page with a databound multi-select jquery dropdown. This works nicley but how can i get hold of the selected items in the code behind?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us which specific plug-in you're using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `jquery dropdown cheklist`. Here is how you can get selected items
http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html
see line `261`.

Comment: I added the link to their current demo page.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Select Items by using below Code and store this selected item in an array for further need.

```
var phddoc = new Array();
            $.each($("#phddoct").next().find('input').filter(':checked'), function() {
                phddoc.push($(this).val());


            });
```

here 'phddoct' is the id of the select box[multiselect object]

best wishes..
shareef m2d